# does indexedDB specification support saving items with null value?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, indexeddb

I'm trying to save an item with null value on an indexedDB.
 it works well on all browsers. but on IE11, I get this error message "Invalid argument.". the only way to save it, is by using undefined as value.
Googling about it, I didn't find any details. I'm wondering if indexedDB specification doesn't allow it or it's a bug on IE implementation?

Comment: Have you tried reading it? www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Comment: You should be able to store a null value _within an object_.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: not all, I'm  too lazy to read the whole specification. but a quick search throw the page for the "null" word didn't give any satisfying answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it violate database constraint (unique index, primary key, etc), null and undefined are valid record value since it can be structurally clone. Don't count on ie, it will not follow the standard.

Comment: i send to them an feedback (the only way to tell them about a bug). I'm still not sure if they will fix it any time soon:https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813622/indexeddb-on-ie-doesnt-support-putting-null-values